# Can you pull user inputs from one def function as use them in another def function?

Tags: python, typeerror, user-defined-functions

I've only been working on python for a few weeks and I'm stuck on this def function issue. I was planning on using the user inputs from the first function as part of a logical expression and then a combination equation I wrote, each time I attempt this it returns as a Type error stating it's missing 2 positional arguments for x and y. Is there some notation I'm missing to use the same variables twice in the same equation.

```
def main():
        def intro():
                 print("hello")
                 import math
                 x = eval(input("#?"))
                 y = eval(input("#?"))
                 if x <= 0:
                     print("error")    
                 else:
                     print((math.factorial(x)))
                 if y > x:
                     print("error")
                 else:
                     print ((math.factorial(y)))
                 port(x,y)
        def port(x,y):
            import math
           
            nCr=(math.factorial(x)/((math.factorial(y)*math.factorial(x - y))))            
            print(nCr)

            print(" you can have a total of", nCr, "combinations")
            return x
            return y
        intro()
        port()
    
main()
```

I hoped the x and y inputs would be used for all positions in the nCr equation but that seems to be where the error occurs.

Comment: It's because you're unnecessarily calling `port()` at the end of `main()`

Comment: Also, you can combine your `intro()` and `port()` functions into one. Is there reason you haven't already?

Answer (score 0):

So when you call the port() function, you're not passing any arguments to it (it expects two arguments, x and y). Also, the x and y variables are local to the intro() function and are not accessible outside of it. This code below should work:

```
import math

def intro():
    print("hello")
    x = eval(input("#?"))
    y = eval(input("#?"))
    if x <= 0:
        print("error")
    else:
        print(math.factorial(x))
    if y > x:
        print("error")
    else:
        print(math.factorial(y))
    port(x, y)

def port(x, y):
    nCr = math.factorial(x) / (math.factorial(y) * math.factorial(x - y))
    print("You can have a total of", nCr, "combinations")
    return x, y

intro()
```